# Read xml file upload in extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I want make upload form and read contents xml file uploaded, in sencha architect and extjs.Anybody have demo or experience share with me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need more than just ExtJS. You need something like PHP, ASP, or other on the server. Because you have not indicated any of these, it is not possible to answer your question.